# Android What is the difference between calling AsyncTask.execute vs. extending the AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In Android What is the difference / Advantage between calling AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable.. vs. extending the AsyncTask and calling doInBackground(..)?

On some time interval I will use HttpURLConnection to POST to a server and retrieve information.  I am not sure which is the preferred method for handling this type of action.

Answer (score 0):

A class that extends AsyncTask can have a constructor with parameters and then you can use this values inside that class. This way your AsyncTask can have different parameters with different types. I don't see any other advantatge.

I prefer using ThreadPoolExecutor instead of AsyncTask to increase performance, from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads, consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed tasks.

However, for API connections I prefer using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), give it a try.

Comment: Thanks,  I can look into it but, as of now I am being told to use HttpURLConnection and AsyncTask.  Does anyone know the difference / pros and cons to using AsyncTask.execute vs.  extending AsyncTask and calling doInBackground?
Thanks

Comment: For me the only difference is the possibility of using the constructor with parameters, as I've said. It's a good advantage but only if you want to pass more than one parameter of different types. By extending an asynctask you are not forced to only one parameter type. Also you can add private methods to that class that extends asynctask if you want. With ThreadPoolExecutor you can also execute HttpUrlConnection more efficiently than with the old AsyncTask but you can do this both ways.